# ¿como utilizar las cabezeras en una petición GET, para conectarse a una base de datos u otra, en tiempo de ejecución?

Tags: nodejs

Quiero hacer peticiones a un API con node.js, y dependiendo de las cabezeras, se harán consultas SQL a un servidor u otro. En las cabezeras viene la informacion de dbUser, dbPassword, dbServer, dbDatabase

```
connection.js

import sql from "mssql";
import config from "../config";

export const dbSettings = {
  user: config.dbUser,
  password: config.dbPassword,
  server: config.dbServer,
  database: config.dbDatabase,
  options: {
    encrypt: true, // for azure
    trustServerCertificate: true, // change to true for local dev / self-signed certs
  },
};

export const getConnection = async () => {
  try {
    const pool = await sql.connect(dbSettings);
    console.log('dbsetings: ', dbSettings);
    return pool;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

Intento utilizar este middleware para cambiar las variables de entorno en tiempo de ejecución de una petición GET, pero no cambian, son siempre las mismas, las que tengo en el archivo .env

```
app.js

...

import config from "./config";

// Middlewares

app.use("/api", function (req, res, next) {
    process.env.DB_USER = req.headers.db_user
    process.env.DB_PASSWORD = req.headers.db_password
    process.env.DB_SERVER = req.headers.db_server
    process.env.DB_DATABASE = req.headers.db_database
    next();
});

...
```

Este es el archivo config que lee los datos desde un .env:

```
config.js

import { config } from "dotenv";
config();

export default {
  port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
  dbUser: process.env.DB_USER || "",
  dbPassword: process.env.DB_PASSWORD || "",
  dbServer: process.env.DB_SERVER || "",
  dbDatabase: process.env.DB_DATABASE || "",
};
```

Comment: Creo que esta respuesta te puede ayudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59971381/change-env-variables-at-runtime La consulta de google fue:"node js change environment variables in runtime"

Comment: Ok, esta claro, no sabia este comportamiento de los proceso en node.js, gracias por la ayuda.